# www.sample.com automatically redirected to sample.com

Tags: url, nginx, dns, linode

I'm running two sites on Linode.  Testing server.

I have one Wordpress site running on sample.com
I have another Ghost site that I want to run on www.sample.com

Note: the first one doesn't have www prefix

However when I try to access www.sample.com my browser instantly shows my Wordpress site at sample.com ( the one without www )

I can not narrow down where this setting is being enforced at.

I figure it either has to be in the Linode DNS settings  -OR-  in the nginx server settings.  I can't find anything indicating that there should be a redirect of any kind.

**Ammendment**: On the nginx side, there is are two configuration files.  The default server config file is pointing to the Wordpress installation which is loading for both www and non-www cases.

**Ammendment**: The remaining 1 configuration file is pointing to the Ghost installation.

**Ammendment**: When using the same two configuration files, but only changing the hostname to be "mail." instead of "www." the ghost installation loads just fine.  The "mail." host was already registered in the dns settings, so I just borrowed it as a test.

What am I not consdering?

Comment: Richard, yes, you are correct.  Let me correct that so that they are all the same.

Comment: It may be useful to look at the output from `nginx -T` and search for any mention of `www`.

Comment: Richard, I'm not sure what happened.  But, just now it started working.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that my browser was caching the the urls and automatically forwarding them.  Either the browser or something.  Somewhere??  I actually tried a different browser that I normally don't use, and it gave me the same problem though.  I don't know why it's working all of the sudden.

Either way, I appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what happened.  But, 24 hours later, the problem went away.  Somewhere in the pipeline, old host/ip/port sets were getting cached and I couldn't resolve where.  But, now it's working fine.

Thanks Richard Smith for taking time to talk me through it.